# How to access dcm4chee data from another dcm4chee

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

Lets consider a scenario

I have two system  A and B

IP Address A - 192.168.0.1 database IP is 192.168.0.1 for pacs

IP Address B - 192.168.0.2 database IP is 192.168.0.2 for pacs

I have sent dicom image in A using dcmsnd command

how to access system A data from system B

So what i need to configure in system A or system B to access system A's dicom data in system B

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend two options depending on your needs.

**Option 1**

The first option assumes you do actually want redundant data (ie: two separate storage locations and two separate databases) and not just two dcm4chee instances.

In this case you can set up dicom forwarding from A to B. This is setup in the Forward Service bean of dcm4chee (via the jmx-console or via the jboss twiddle.sh script). More complex forwarding (ie: based on modalities) can be configured in the Forward Service2 bean.

The official docs are here:

- [Forward Service](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Forward+Service)
- [Forward Service2](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Forward+Service2)

If you need more details, I have written a blog post that goes into more depth about using and setting up Forward Service here:

- [DCM4CHEE: PACS SYNCHRONIZATION VIA DICOM FORWARDING](http://davidsimic.com/2016/07/30/dcm4chee-pacs-synchronization-via-dicom-forwarding/)

**Option 2**

The second option assumes you don't really need data redundancy, but you do need two separate dcm4chee instances.

No problem. You can setup two dcm4chee instances on separate boxes to share the same database (which lives either at 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.2 or perhaps somewhere else) and storage device.

For this to really work, you will need to configure both dcm4chee instances to not only connect to the same db, but to also store their archives on the same shared network storage device which you mount on each box.

The storage directory is configured via the DefaultStorageDirectory property of the FileSystemMgt group=ONLINE_STORAGE bean in the jmx-console.

*Note: My answer assumes the dcm4chee-2.x series, and not the successor arc-light series (though the steps should be conceptually similar in either case - ie: setup forwarding or shared storage).*